# Division returning incorrect number - C#/XNA

Tags: c#, math, xna

I have an image (1280x1024) which I want as a background on my game menu, with a margin of 64px around the left, right and top of the image.

Because the game window can be resized, the image needs to be rescaled to a specific size, this is easy with the width of the image which is just `windowWidth - 128`, however the height is harder to pull off, because the bottom of the image is supposed to disappear off of the end of the window.

Currently, I am trying to use the resolution of the image and the width it is to be drawn as to calculate a scale, which is then used to calculate the correct height for the image, like so:

```
image.Height / (int)(((float) image.Height) / (windowWidth - 128)));
```

When the window size is 1024x768, this always seems to return 1024 as the height (and 896 as the width, which is correct). This causes the image to be to tall in the menu and thus warped inproperly.

Is there a better way to scale the image correctly, or have I missed something trivial?

Comment: There is no floating-point division in the code that you've shown.

Comment: I was going on the principle of 'keep it simple, stupid' when I wrote this, but yes - I do agree that I should have floating point division in there, though it still made no difference when I had it in my code

Comment: A better principle is "show us the code you actually wrote".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the code is not exhibiting the problem asked

Answer (score 2):

You are using [integer divisions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691373%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Try:

```
b = f / ((e * 1.0) / a)
```

Or

```
 b = f / ((float) e) / a
```

Comment: Neither of these methods return an integer, which the rectangle constructor argument requires. Also, both of these still return 1120, which continues to baffle me.